# What really happened in this scene?

Tags: valerian-and-city-thousand-planets

In the scene where the fisherman bought some pearls to queen, the queen took
one pearl, said some prayer and gave it back to the fisherman.

After that the fisherman gave it to a female alien and told her to give it to her sister. After receiving the pearl from the female alien, her sister fed to some creature and the creature popped some pearls out from its body.

[image]

**What's going on here?**

Comment: aah, this is pretty easy to explain. Completely illogical dumbassery and poor decisions in both design and directing. See, it's pretty clear the comic writers or besson decided to make a mockery of the story right off the bat. What better way to do it than in instantaneous mass replication of any object no matter the composition being ejected from some rainbow armadillo's assal region? ... pfft!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The creature is a Mül Converter. These adorable critters come from the planet Mül. They're capable of reproducing any object by eating it and excreting hundreds of replicas. ([source](https://www.space.com/37560-valerian-weirdest-aliens.html) slide 7 of 18).

Toward the end of the movie, one of the surviving 'Pearls' (The Pearls are a peaceful, holistic race of humanoids who come from the planet Mül [source](https://www.space.com/37560-valerian-weirdest-aliens.html) slide 8 of 18.) explains that they periodically 'give back' to the planet (Mül) they live on.

> Our planet is very beautiful and we live in harmony with the elements.
>   Our activities are fishing and collecting energy.
>   That energy makes fertile soil, control the wind and the waves.
>   Two years we performed on land and sea.
>   We lived in harmony for centuries.
>   Until doomsday arrives.

[quote source](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=valerian-and-the-city-of-a-thousand-planets)